# android Thread Textviev write problem

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

İ want to write textview a simple word via Thread but it is force close

codes is that :

```
package thread.denemesi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class baslat extends Activity {
   Button buton1,buton2;
   Thread thread2,thread1;
   TextView yazi;
   int sayi=0;
   ArrayList<Integer> dizi;
   int sayac=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        buton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        yazi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        dizi=new ArrayList<Integer>();



        buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                thread1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                //      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    //      dizi.add(i);


                //      }   
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                            sayac++;
                            try {
                                yazi.setText("i want to write a word");
                                Thread.sleep(100);

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        }               
                    }); 
                thread1.start();
            }
        });




    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should have used `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

You would find that your exception is something like "Attempted to modify the UI from a non-UI thread".

You will need to call `setText()` from the main application thread, not your background thread. You can do this via:

- a `Handler`
- calling `post()` on your `TextView`, passing a `Runnable`
- calling `runOnUiThread()` on your `Activity`, passing a `Runnable`

Comment: İ want to add view to layout via thread but it now work..same error

Comment: @metin: Of course. You cannot modify the UI from a background thread. Use any of the techniques I mentioned in the answer to move your add-view-to-layout logic to the main application thread.

Comment: i Solved..İf you want to add or change somethink on Main layout you should write your code in OnResume() fonction..Thank you